# PL/SQL - How to find out values missing from table by comparing to another table

Tags: oracle, grid, subquery, mapping, coordinates

I am building my knowledge of using SQL by using the basic 10x10 (-5 to 5) grid system on the game battleships to work out which grids avoid getting hit over a series of games.

I have come up with the following queries, to compare the X and Y grids on the board (`game`) to a table containing 11 rows of the -5 to 5 (including 0) numbers used per axis (`grid_format`). I have inserted 9 lines of test data (some of which are on the same grids).

The result should return about 114 rows, instead I only get 49 rows. Individually, the `x_coord` and `y_coord` queries return 7 rows, excluding the ones that were used on `game`, meaning that it is working. The problem lies with bringing them together, where entire `y_coord` grids are omitted.

Both these queries have given me the same result. Is anyone able to help me solve this dilemma please?

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE game(
x_coord NUMBER(2,0),
y_coord NUMBER(2,0));

INSERT INTO game VALUES (4,4);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (1,-4);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (0,0);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (0,0);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (1,-5);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (1,-5);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (-2,4);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (1,-5);
INSERT INTO game VALUES (0,0);

CREATE TABLE grid_format(
grid NUMBER(2,0));

INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-5);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-4);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-3);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-2);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-1);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (-0);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO grid_format VALUES (5);

-- Query

SELECT X_Grid, Y_Grid
FROM
(SELECT grid AS Y_Grid
FROM grid_format
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM game
        WHERE game.y_coord = grid_format.grid)),
(SELECT grid AS X_Grid 
FROM grid_format
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM game
        WHERE game.x_coord = grid_format.grid)
 ORDER BY X_Grid DESC);


 -- Alternative Solution


SELECT X_Grid, Y_Grid
FROM
   (SELECT grid AS X_Grid
   FROM grid_format
MINUS
   SELECT x_coord
   FROM game),
   (SELECT grid AS Y_Grid
   FROM grid_format
MINUS
   SELECT y_coord
   FROM game)
```

Here are the results for the test (see link):

[Result from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD0E5.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You've put a lot of effort into your question, thanks! It is easier for us if you supply the create table statements and some example data, as explained for instance [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question).

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, I have added it in now.

Comment: You are still missing insert statements for `game` table.

Comment: Ye, sorry again. I have included it this time and uploaded the results I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
WITH 
  xaxis AS (SELECT grid AS x FROM grid_format),
  yaxis AS (SELECT grid AS y FROM grid_format),
  grid  AS (SELECT x, y FROM xaxis, yaxis)
SELECT *
  FROM grid
  LEFT JOIN game 
    ON grid.x = game.x_coord
   AND grid.y = game.y_coord;
```

which returns all the grid positions (x,y) and, if there is a ship, a value in X_COORD and Y_COORD, something like

```
 X   Y   X_COORD   Y_COORD
 3   3   3         3
-5   2      
-2   5      
 3  -5      
-2  -4
```

EDIT:

You could even display the grid graphically with something like

```
WITH 
  xaxis AS (SELECT grid AS x_coord FROM grid_format),
  yaxis AS (SELECT grid AS y_coord FROM grid_format),
  grid  AS (SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM xaxis, yaxis),
  grid2 AS (SELECT x_coord, y_coord, NVL2(game.rowid,1,0) as ship
             FROM grid LEFT JOIN game USING(x_coord, y_coord))
SELECT * 
  FROM grid2
 PIVOT (sum(ship) 
        FOR x_coord IN (-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
 ORDER BY y_coord;

 -5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 -4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 -3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 -2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: THAT is amazing! didnt know you could display the graphics like that! Thank you very much.